# navigation to a new page fails

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a page in a windows phone app. In this page there are some times. User can delete this items by pressing a delete button.Previously  When a back button was pressed then the user could saw the deleted item and it causes error to the program. SO i override the back button and stop it works. And i made my own back button on my app and when the user press the back button of my app it will navigate to the main page.
I used this codes:

```
 protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;  //Cancels the default behavior.

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage_page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

But the navigation to main page doesn't work. How can i solve this??

Is it possible to navigate to the main page by pressing the Phone's back button like this:

```
 protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;  //Cancels the default behavior.
         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage_page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage_page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

To:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Unless you've renamed the page of course.

Answer (score 0):

This may be help you.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
       // e.Cancel = true; 
         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage_page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

Your button click event seems OK there is no problem on navigation to main page.

//Seems OK

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage_page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

If i guess right there are some other Navigation in MainPage_page.xaml OnNavigatedTo  method

//Review your MainPage_page.xaml

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: If i use navigation code in OnBackKeyPress then the error shows in that that: // Code to execute if a navigation fails
        private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

Comment: looking to the exception, I would suggest you to check your page name, is "/MainPage_page.xaml" a correct path? This exception occurs when the relative path given is not found.